# Overlap bootstrap carousel with image from navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page, where I use a full-screen bootstrap carousel for sliding images and a `navbar` at the top of the page (not fixed).

Now there should be a logo inside the `navbar`, that overlaps it's height at the bottom and therefore overlaps the carousel.

My problem is that the logo pokes out of the `navbar`, leading to images in the carousel being slid down.

See for yourself at http://strauss.co.at/reini/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `img` tag inside the div with an id of `logo` the following CSS attributes: `z-index: 1;` and `position: absolute`. That's all!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css below:

```
#logo{
 position: absolute;
 z-index:1;
}
```